# Retrieve webpage content that requires login - Invoke-WebRequest - no Forms returned - no Value for password InputField

Tags: powershell, authentication, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to save the content of a webpage that requires session login; I've tried to use wget with the useragent and username (e/login) and password (p/password) inputs and trying to save the cookies file, but realised that nothing got written in. Then I moved on to this method (in PowerShell 6):

```
$R = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://app.asana.com/-/login" -UserAgent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0" -SessionVariable asana
```

but then when I'm trying

```
$Form = $R.Forms[0]
```

There is no forms.

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:1
+ $Form = $R.Forms[0]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

The inputs fields are as follows:

```
 $R.InputFields

outerHTML : <input type="hidden" name="u" value="https://app.asana.com/?rr=296832" />
tagName   : INPUT
type      : hidden
name      : u
value     : https://app.asana.com/?rr=296832

outerHTML : <input type="hidden" name="i" value="password" />
tagName   : INPUT
type      : hidden
name      : i
value     : password

outerHTML : <input type="hidden" name="src" value="login" />
tagName   : INPUT
type      : hidden
name      : src
value     : login

outerHTML : <input type="hidden" name="auth" />
tagName   : INPUT
type      : hidden
name      : auth

outerHTML : <input type="hidden" name="xsrf_token" value="60a3a8255cfe364b3fbec08ec6c2106e:1578648571483" />
tagName   : INPUT
type      : hidden
name      : xsrf_token
value     : 60a3a8255cfe364b3fbec08ec6c2106e:1578648571483

outerHTML : <input tabindex="1" type="email" name="e" id="email_input" value="" />
tagName   : INPUT
tabindex  : 1
type      : email
name      : e
id        : email_input
value     :

outerHTML : <input tabindex="2" type="password" name="p" id="password_input" />
tagName   : INPUT
tabindex  : 2
type      : password
name      : p
id        : password_input
```

So now I can access the username (i.e. the email) directly:

```
$R.InputFields[5].Value="nats@email"
```

But there is no Value property for InputFields[6] which is the password.

```
Exception setting "Value": "The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
```

I can't work out an alternative way of inputting the password.
Or maybe there is a different method altogether?

Once I'm logged in, I'm going to access the webpage that I want (within the session) and save the content with -OutFile..

Comment: In the end I'm using Selenium and saving the page source. Will be still very interested to hear what the solution could be here.